# How to check pair of string values in a column, after grouping the dataframe using ID column?

Tags: pandas, filter, group-by, series

[My Doubt in a Table/Dataframe view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4kXc.png)I have a dataframe containing 2 columns: ID and Code.

```
ID Code Flag
1   A   0
1   C   1
1   B   1
2   A   0
2   B   1
3   A   0
4   C   0
```

Within each ID, if Code 'A' exists with 'B' or 'C', then it should flag 1.

I tried Groupby('ID') with filter(). but it is not showing the perfect result. Could anyone please help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

First use `pd.groupby('ID')` and concatenate the codes using `'sum'` to create a new column. Then assing the value `1` if a row contains `A` or `B` as `Code` and when the new column contains an `A`:

```
df['s'] = df.groupby('ID').Code.transform('sum')
df['Flag'] = 0
df.loc[((df.Code == 'B') | (df.Code == 'C')) & df.s.str.contains('A'), 'Flag'] = 1
df = df.drop(columns = 's')
```

Output:

```
   ID Code  Flag
0   1    A     0
1   1    C     1
2   1    B     1
3   2    A     0
4   2    B     1
5   3    A     0
6   4    C     0
```

Comment: Thank You so much @Tobias for the quick solution and reply. It is working as expected now. <3

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean masks, direct for B/C, per group for A, then combine them and convert to integer:

```
# is the Code a B or C?
m1 = df['Code'].isin(['B', 'C'])
# is there also a A in the same group?
m2 = df['Code'].eq('A').groupby(df['ID']).transform('any')

# if both are True, flag 1
df['Flag'] = (m1&m2).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   ID Code  Flag
0   1    A     0
1   1    C     1
2   1    B     1
3   2    A     0
4   2    B     1
5   3    A     0
6   4    C     0
```

Comment: Thank You so much @mozway for the efforts and quick reply. It is working now.

Comment: NB. I see you're shuffling with the tick mark. You can only mark **one** answer as accepted ;)

Comment: Yes, I was giving "Accepted" to both the answers. I am new to this platform. :)